# How do I pass URL parameter via jQuery source?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass an ID via jQuery to a method in PHP, but it's not happening:

```
$(function(){
    $("#link").autocomplete({
        source: base_url + "bookmarks/jq_get_bookmarks_by_search_as_object/" + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('ul.ui-autocomplete').removeAttr('style').hide().appendTo('.link-results').show();
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.link-results').append('<div class="bookmark-search-box" id="bookmark-search-box-' + ui.item.bookmark_id + '"><input type="checkbox" id="bookmark-search-item-' + ui.item.bookmark_id + '" name="bookmark-search-items[]" value="' + ui.item.bookmark_id + '" checked="checked">' + ui.item.title + '<div>');
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>').data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a>' + item.snippet + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

I've emboldened the offending line of code. You'll see that I'm attempting to append the URL string with the last parameter of the URL.

Any ideas would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: I'll apologise in advance for the confusing title! If any moderator wants to edit that to read: "How do I pass...", that would be excellent.

Comment: You can edit your post too

Comment: Just to be clear, the value at added to the end of the source URL needs to a number and not a name-value pair; the application is expecting and only works with a URI segment.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
source: base_url + "bookmarks/jq_get_bookmarks_by_search_as_object/" + $("#bookmark-active").val()
```